# cannot connect with ssh to linux after shutdown command

Tags: linux, ssh, shutdown

i've used command `shutdown -h 12:55` (for example), and linux server shutdowned at this time, but when I'm trying to connect with ssh I receive the message:

```
"The system is going down on Thu Dec 31 12:56:30 2015".
```

It's an ssh issue because when I access the server physically I can type any command.

Comment: if you shut down server, you can't access it. You need to turn it on before. If you are asking for something else, please clarify.

Comment: server is up and works. but i cant connect with ssh. wen i try there is message 'The system is going down on Thu Dec 31 12:56:30 2015'

Answer (score 3):

From manual page for the **[shutdown](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/shutdown.html)** command provided by systemd:

> If the time argument is used, 5 minutes before the system goes down the `/run/nologin` file is created to ensure that further logins shall not be allowed.

You're also probably using the **[pam_nologin](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_nologin.8.html)** module which:

> prevents users from logging into the system when `/var/run/nologin` or `/etc/nologin` exists. The contents of the file are displayed to the user. The pam_nologin module has no effect on the root user's ability to log in.

Take note that since most of the time `/var/run` is just a symlink to `/run`, if `/run/nologin` exists, so does `/var/run/nologin`.

So you have wrong time or the file persisted over the shutdown for some reason and if you delete it, you should be fine.

Comment: The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard 3.0](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s15.html) says that "Files under this directory [i.e. `/run`] must be cleared (removed or truncated as appropriate) at the beginning of the boot process." and systemd uses _tmpfs_ for the `/run` directory, so it would be hard for `/run/nologin` to persist between reboots.